# How do you start activity indicator?

Tags: iphone

I want to start an activity indicator whenever the user presses any link on a webview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First assign the ViewController which the UIWebView appears in as its delegate: Do this either by control-dragging from the UIWebView to the File's Owner object in InterfaceBuilder or in code:

```
[myWebView setDelegate:myViewController];
```

Then in your ViewController.m file you can now use the [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) methods to detect when pages are being loaded. These delegate methods will be triggered every time a link or new page is loaded in the UIWebView.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna show network activity indicator just put

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

and then

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

when you wanna hide it

while if you needs UIActivityIndicator

you have to define it in your controller then Outlet it in XIB and then

show

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

hide

```
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidStartLoad:)

It will allow your delegate to be notified whenever the webview is starting to load new content, which, presumably, is the case whenever a link has been pressed. The delegate method you want is **webViewDidStartLoad:** - in its implementation you could then easily set up or start your activity indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `webViewDidStartLoad:` in `UIWebViewDelegate`.